# Getting current fingers position on Android

Tags: java, android, events, multi-touch

I'm developing an application that needs to get all fingers on the screen of the Android. That's not complex, and I could make it in a few lines of code.

However, the way android sends callbacks is not what I need. I have done many tests, and here is what I could find out:

Once he sent the fingers positions, if no "big" movement has been made, he will not send a onTouch event.

Also, when a finger is REMOVED from the screen (for example: there are 3 fingers, and one is removed), it seems that it ONLY sends the next event, if at least one of the remaining fingers move on the screen.

I'm doing some tracking on fingers, and matching with objects, and to do this properly, I need to know all the fingers positions all the time. If there is not a way to "request" finger's touch event even when it didn't moved, how can I access the current finger positions without an callback event? Is there any other solution?

Here is my code:

```
ArrayList<Vector3> fingerTips = new ArrayList<Vector3>();

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        final int points = event.getPointerCount();
        String out = "==========\n";

        fingerTips.clear();

        for(int i = 0; i < points; i++){
            out += "\tPoint "+i+"\t("+event.getX(i)+", "+event.getY(i) + ")\n";
            fingerTips.add( new Vector3(event.getX(i), event.getY(i)) );
        }

        Log.i(TAG, out);

        // Send touches to SurfaceView
        chwaziViewGL.onUpdateFingerTips(fingerTips);

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that I didn't received one `event` with all the finger positions AFTER removing a finger...

After lot's of tests and logging, I discovered that it's true (in part).

Whenever you REMOVE a finger on the SCREEN, the NEXT event sent is an `ACTION_POINTER_UP` or `ACTION_UP`, meaning that the finger `x` is no longer touching the screen.

Since there was NO motion after removing the finger, the last `MotionEvent` sent was the `UP`, containg the removed finger also.

So, to fix that, I check if the action is `UP`, and on the loop that get's all the fingers, I created an if checking if that was the finger removed from the screen. If so, I just didn't add it to the array.

Here is my final code:

```
ArrayList<Vector3> fingerTips = new ArrayList<Vector3>();

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        final int points = event.getPointerCount();

        // Check if it's an event that a finger
        // was removed, if so, set removedPoint
        int removedPoint = -1;
        final int action = event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;

        if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
            removedPoint = (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) 
                    >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;


        String out = "==========\n";

        fingerTips.clear();

        for(int i = 0; i < points; i++){
            // Find out pointer ID
            int pointerID = event.getPointerId(i);
            if(pointerID == MotionEvent.INVALID_POINTER_ID){
                out += "\tPoint "+pointerID+" INVALID\n";
                continue;
            }

            // Check if it's the removed finger
            if(removedPoint == i){
                out += "\tPoint "+pointerID+" REMOVED\n";
                continue;
            }

            out += "\tPoint "+pointerID+"\t("+event.getX(i)+", "+event.getY(i) + ")\n";
            fingerTips.add( new Vector3(event.getX(i), event.getY(i), pointerID) );
        }

        Log.i(TAG, out);

        // Send touches to SurfaceView
        chwaziViewGL.onUpdateFingerTips(fingerTips);

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but your code cost me a lot of hairs;-(( After days I found the problem finally before I got insane. This code

```
final int action = event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;

if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        removedPoint = (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) 
                >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
```

could have never been worked!!!

Why? Because if you mask the value that is coming from getAction() it is simply a plain integer value of the action. And when you try to use this plain value and masking it again with something, it has no meaning at all!

The correction is to use again event.getAction() in the seconds masking:

```
removedPoint = (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) 
                >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
```

It was really a nightmare to find this. But anyway, I think you just wanted the best and help others:-))) Its ok.